# Schengen visa C: invite people planning to reside somewhere else

Tags: schengen-visas, proof-of-accommodation, visitor

I'm a European and some of my wife's family will come to visit and has to apply for a Schengen visa: short stay (C).
There's two ways to go:

1.) for reason of friends or family visit

2.) for tourism

the former one needs an invitation letter, while the latter one needs all hotel bookings to be spelled out (and is thus less flexible). Now my question is: can we let them go for 1) and pretend they will stay over at our place, while they'll actually decide to spend the night at a hotel nearby, or would that bring them in trouble? And what should they respond when the immigration officers ask them about their plans?

Comment: Willfully misrepresenting travel plans is **NEVER** a good idea, DON'T do that

Comment: Which EU country specifically? IIRC some may require such an invitation letter to be attested or otherwise registered officially. Regardless, *deliberately* misrepresenting plans is never a good idea. How would *you* respond if when your wife’s family arrives at the border Immigration contacted you to ask you to confirm they will be staying with you?

Comment: @Traveller would stay that they are staying nearby, in close contact with us and they can allways fall back on our place. Which is the truth. Actually, taking a closer look, the application form mentions "host or accomodation" under references, and we are probably more useful as a reference since we are a close contact. Upon rereading, it's a little ambiguous as whether host literally means person people stay overnight with. And making reasonable adjustments to travel plans after issuing the visa is allowed.

Comment: pre-planned adjustments are not adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to be specific without knowning the specific country, but think through the **purpose of an invitation.** It is twofold or threefold.

- The invitation explains why the visitor wants to travel there and then. If a visitor were to say that he or she wants to visit, say,  [Coesfeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coesfeld) for two weeks in November to see the tourist sights, that is not plausible unless the visitor has a special interest in meat-packing plants. If a visitor wants to go there to stay with family or in-laws for two weeks, that's entirely reasonable.
- The invitation usually explains *part of the funding* for the trip, lowering the expected cost of living expenses for the visitor.
- In some Schengen states, a sponsor can *formally guarantee* to cover costs, including those of a deliberate or involuntary overstay (e.g. for medical reasons). That might make a visit possible if the personal circumstances of the guest would otherwise prevent it.

Even with an invitation letter promising to cover all expenses in country, the authorities will still want to see the financial details of the applicant. They want to gauge the economic situation at home and if there is a good job to *return to*. They also check if the cost of the trip is in proportion to the income and savings. (Few reasonable persons will spend several years of disposable income on a night in the opera. Spending that much to migrate and overstay is more rational.)

So if it is *reasonable under the conditions* for your relatives to visit and to stay in a hotel, then you should write a letter confirming the reason for the visit and that they plan to stay in a hotel. To that, add the hotel reservation. The visa officials will take the invitation into account for the premise of the trip, and look at the finances of your guests for the funding. If the finances of your relatives don't look good, you should spell out what you will cover (e.g. meals but not housing) to reduce their daily cost of subsistence while they are in the Schengen area. But it would be easier if they have enough money to cover that as well.